# vercel serveless function and nextjs Api routes

Tags: javascript, next.js, serverless, vercel

When deploying nextjs on vercel, the codes of the two function points of vercel's serveless function and nextjs's Api Routes seem to be the same again. Should we deploy it as Vercel serveless function or  as nextjs Api routes? Who works at last

if I write the code completely in the nextjs way and deploy it to vercel, will vercel convert the relevant code into vercel's serveless function?

I don't seem to have found a description of both in their official documents

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.